# Using foreach to create new observations and deleting erroneous observations in parallel

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, data-cleaning

I am currently trying to clean a very large data set.  I have working code to clean it, but it takes about three days to run without any parallelization, so I want to parallelize it.  The original code works fine, but I can't figure out how to parallelize it in R using the doParallel and foreach packages or any other pre-built ones.

In particular, if I observe two data points that have the same time stamp, they should really be one data point. The non-parallelized code can accurately identify the points, flag them to be deleted later and create a new data point that is correct.

I've tried adapting existing code to convert the for loops into foreach loops using the %do% option provided by the doParallel package.  Doing this works fine.  Changing the %do% to %dopar% causes the code to stop working.  I understand that this is the incorrect way to use %dopar%, but I don't know how to correctly accomplish my goal.

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  date = c(10, 1, 9, 4, 11),
                  var2 = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
                  var3 = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
                  ind = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))  #Indicator for problem observations

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  date = c(12, 10, 7, 5, 6),
                  var2 = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
                  var3 = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
                  ind = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

foreach (row1 = 1:nrow(df1)) %dopar% {
  for (row2 in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    if(df1[row1, "date"] == df2[row2, "date"]) { #Observations that occur on the same date should be combined
      df1[row1, "ind"] <- 1  #Tag problem observations to delete them later
      df2[row2, "ind"] <- 1
      temp_obs <- data.frame(ID = df2[row2, "ID"],
                             date = df1[row1, "date"],
                             var2 = df1[row1, "var2"],
                             var3 = df1[row1, "var3"] + df2[row2, "var3"],
                             ind = 0)
      df1 <- rbind(df1, temp_obs)
      rm(temp_obs)
      }
  }
}
```

The sample code demonstrates my problem in a simpler context.  It loops through all observations in df1 and df2, and identifies observations with the same date.  It should add a 6th observation to df1, and change the indicators from 0 to 1 in the 1st entry of df1 and the second entry of df2 to indicate that they have been matched.  As is, this code does not change df1 or df2 at all.  It works when %dopar% is replaced with %do%.

Comment: From the toy example this seems like it could be an XY problem - less about parallelization and more about having settled on a *really* inefficient way to achieve the goal.  You might get a better response if you give a clearer example of the end goal:  I have this, I want that.

Comment: As a starter, `foreach()` is *not* a replacement to a `for(...)` loop.  For this and other few other things, you might be interested in https://www.jottr.org/2019/01/11/parallelize-a-for-loop-by-rewriting-it-as-an-lapply-call/.  It was written to help with questions like this. (Disclaimer: I'm the author)

Comment: You should use `duplicated()` instead of a double for-loop, it would be much faster I think.

Comment: To clarify, the issue I'm trying to solve is that I observe shipments that go from A to B, and B to C, when they really should go from A to C.  To identify the issues, I'm searching for observations where one's starting point starts at another's end point on the same day and then creating a new observation with the correct information.

`duplicated()` won't solve this because all the observations are distinct and I need to create new observations, and I've subsetted the data as much as I can to search only over the smallest part of potentially erroneous observations.

Comment: The point I was making is that instead of asking for help in speeding up an inefficient solution through parallelization, you'd be better off asking for help in working out a better solution altogether.  The nested loops can probably be replaced with vectorized operations and you should absolutely avoid binding dataframes inside loops.  Dealing with just these two issues will result in a significant increase in speed but you haven't provided enough details on your expected output and how to arrive there for anyone to offer further help.